# How can i get the content of uploaded file in php?

Tags: php

I can upload a file by using html file type and then I store that file information to mysql db.  Here's my code=>

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"]));
$document_name = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
$document_link = $upload['url'];
//and DB Operations in here..(I store to db filename,date,filelink etc.)
```

My problem is, I can't read the file content to store it to db.  (I will do search on the file content, so I must read content of file.)  Briefly how can i read the content of a file like pdf, doc or etc. from url such as http://...../uploads/exampleFile.docx?

Answer (score 48):

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);
```

Refer to the manual: [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) for an overview and this tutorial: [Tizag PHP - File Upload](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) for a walkthrough.

This PHP Manual section is a must-read as well: [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) - moved from hakre's comment.

Comment: This PHP Manual section is a must-read as well: [Handling File UPloads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Thanks michael, i used this code but this output is not understandable for human side.. This code produces output like binary code.For example=>($4��V"e�ˤ9�B��A���)j���T(�y�>vw�餶ث�v�(�SL���qW�U�DX��˿Q�w��4S�^� ��0�F�"м�\�gsld�Y�dL�uH�����݂��c9>)=>output get like this. I can't get output like human understandable

Comment: Without extra work you're not going to be able to read doc or pdf files. Refer to http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php for a way to do this.