# AJAX not posting FormData

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file with AJAX. This is my first time ever using FormData.

On my client side script I just loop through the $_FILES and echo each, just for confirmation that they're being sent, and they're not. I checked the $_POST array too, but that is empty as well. The server-side script is being called though, just doesn't appear to be receiving any data from JavaScript.

Here is my code,  what am I doing wrong?

The JS

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
function upload(){
    var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
    client.open("post", "/orl_ajax_uploader.php", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    client.send(formData);
    return false;
}
client.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200){
        alert(client.response);
    }
}
```

The HTML

```
<form action="orl_ftp.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return upload()">
    <table>
       <tr>
        <td>Choose File: </td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="uploadfile" multiple /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Process"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The PHP (for testing only)

```
$str = "POST PARAMS // ";
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
    $str .= $k."=".$v." :: ";
}
$str .= "FILES PARAMS // ";
foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v){
    $str .= $k."=".$v." :: ";
}
$str .= "GET PARAMS // ";
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
    $str .= $k."=".$v." :: ";
}
$str .= '"'.$_FILES['upload'].'"';
echo $str;
```

When I hit submit PHP sends back this string every time: `POST PARAMS // FILES PARAMS // GET PARAMS // ""` in addition to an undefined index error for trying to call `$_FILES['upload']` ..which should be there, but isn't..

**EDIT**
[image: It's being sent..]

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for a warning, or monitored the network traffic to make sure the request is being created/sent properly? And are you sure you're using a browser that supports `FormData` and/or `XMLHttpRequest2`?

Comment: I don't know how it would hurt it, but the examples I've found don't use `client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` like you. Try taking that out and trying?

Comment: @Ian yes, yes, and yes. See the screenshot I added. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: That helped! I don't know why but I get "Array" instead of "" now! Wahoo! If you put it in the answers I will select it! Thank!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` to set the `Content-Type` should not be used with uploading files/form data. The browser handles the generation of the `Content-Type` value, using boundaries and things internal to the request that we don't need to worry about. Not manually setting that request header should allow the browser to correctly include the file in the request and make it available to the server correctly.

Once this is changed, you should be able to access `$_FILES["upload"]`, which is an associative array of attributes. If you need to get the actual contents, use something like `file_get_contents($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])`, otherwise you can get information about the file, like its name, type, etc.

---

**References:**

- [How can i get the content of uploaded file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459864/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-uploaded-file-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Thank you, the extra info really helped me understand the problem

Comment: @Adelphia No problem! I researched it a lot to better understand it, so hopefully you can get it all working together!